# how to scroll window onload with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, resize, horizontal-scrolling

I have a form in the middle of a table. I would like this form to always be in the center of the window vertical and horizontally, even when the window size is smaller than the table.
I am thinking on using the scrollTo function of jQuery and call it onLoad and onResize,
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
but I am a begginer and I don't know how to do it. I would appreciate any help or example with the calls in the header and the script function.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a floater box:
put your form in a DIV , make it's position absolute, center it:
Add this JQuery plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/elementcenter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#div_id').css('position','absolute');
     $('#div_id').center();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
     $('#div_id').center();
});
```

if you want to scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     window.scrollTo(0,$("#FORM_ID").offset().top);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
     window.scrollTo(0,$("#FORM_ID").offset().top);
});
```